# Does Apple/Google provide specifications for iCal field support in iOS or Android?

Tags: android, ios, icalendar, dday

I'm attempting to publish a proprietary software calendar via iCal (using the DDay.iCal package, if that matters) so that customers can view their appointments on their phone or tablet (or in any other piece of software that supports iCal, such as Outlook or Google Calendar). Unfortunately, it seems that the iCal spec provides support for a lot of fields that go unused by these consumers (such as Comment, Status, Categories, Class, and so on), and right now I'm shooting in the dark trying to figure out what is supported and where it gets displayed on the device.

**Does Apple (or Google or Microsoft) publish a list of the iCal fields that they support?**

Answer (score 0):

The iCal format is well documented. Please find the information for example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for specs on the iCal format itself. What I'm looking for is an outline of the supported features within Gmail, Apple's iCal application (not to be confused with the iCal *standard*), etc. The iCal standard supports a LOT of fields that appear to go unused in these applications.